# what does % mean in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
CASE WHEN INV_STOCK_TACKING_HEADER.STK_TACKING_STATUS != 2
                     THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), CONVERT(INT, ( ISNULL(STK_QTY,
                                                              0)
                                                              / ISNULL(dbo.VW_ITEM_UNITS_STK.BIG_TO_BASE_FACTOR,
                                                              0) ))))) + ' / '
                          + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 3), ISNULL(STK_QTY,
                                                              0))
                          % CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 3), ISNULL(dbo.VW_ITEM_UNITS_STK.BIG_TO_BASE_FACTOR,
                                                           0)))
                     ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), CONVERT(INT, ( ISNULL(dbo.INV_STOCK_TACKING_DETAILS.CURRENT_QTY,
                                                              0)
                                                              / ISNULL(dbo.VW_ITEM_UNITS_STK.BIG_TO_BASE_FACTOR,
                                                              0) ))))) + ' / '
                          + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 3), ISNULL(dbo.INV_STOCK_TACKING_DETAILS.CURRENT_QTY,
                                                              0))
                          % CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 3), ISNULL(dbo.VW_ITEM_UNITS_STK.BIG_TO_BASE_FACTOR,
                                                           0)))
                END AS SYSTEM_QTY_EN ,
```

Comment: % is modulo operator, it gives you remaninder.

Comment: It's also a special wildcard character when used with the `LIKE` operator on strings.

Comment: In that context, it's [modulo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). In a string contaxt using `like` or `patindex`, it's a wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` (Modulus)   Divides left hand operand by right hand operand and returns the integer remainder of a division. For example, `5 % 3` will give `2` because the remainder of `5` divided by `3` is `2`

```
select 5%3

result : 2
```